# Drawer is not define

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout

I get an error saying that the drawer is not defined, when I added a gridview.count to the body it is now giving this error which drawer is not define... How do I fix this error?

Here is my scaffold:

```
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[Text('PickerUp')],
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: List.generate(100, (index) {
      return Center(
          child: Text('Item $index',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline));
    }),

    // Drawer controls left menu drawer
    drawer: Container(
      width: 245,
      child: new Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text('Admin'),
              accountEmail: Text('test@admin.com'),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a89c3e38-b6f3-48a0-9f9e-df9a0129fb93/daghh5x-4a77b3ec-fd4f-4d17-9f84-5963a8cb5c03.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2E4OWMzZTM4LWI2ZjMtNDhhMC05ZjllLWRmOWEwMTI5ZmI5M1wvZGFnaGg1eC00YTc3YjNlYy1mZDRmLTRkMTctOWY4NC01OTYzYThjYjVjMDMucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.dWTFMrwnbAbj5TtUp9U_vQsohW7MnkRPymzR5wZQoV8')),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.search),
              title: Text('Search'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
              title: Text('Settings'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              title: Text('Logout'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure about enclosed brackets. Here's your Scaffold

```
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[Text('PickerUp')],
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  // Drawer controls left menu drawer
  drawer: Container(
      width: 245,
      child: new Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text('Admin'),
              accountEmail: Text('test@admin.com'),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/a89c3e38-b6f3-48a0-9f9e-df9a0129fb93/daghh5x-4a77b3ec-fd4f-4d17-9f84-5963a8cb5c03.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2E4OWMzZTM4LWI2ZjMtNDhhMC05ZjllLWRmOWEwMTI5ZmI5M1wvZGFnaGg1eC00YTc3YjNlYy1mZDRmLTRkMTctOWY4NC01OTYzYThjYjVjMDMucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.dWTFMrwnbAbj5TtUp9U_vQsohW7MnkRPymzR5wZQoV8')),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.search),
              title: Text('Search'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
              title: Text('Settings'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              title: Text('Logout'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
  body: new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: List.generate(100, (index) {
      return Center(
          child: Text('Item $index',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline));
    }),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced brackets.

```
  body: new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: List.generate(100, (index) {
      return Center(
          child: Text('Item $index',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline));
    })), <- missed bracket
```